# Extracting a zip using file channel android

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to increase zip extract speed using filechannel but not able to implement it.
Basically i need to get FileInputStream to get a channel.I tried to implement it like

```
FileInputStream inputStream = (FileInputStream)(zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
```

but this gives class cast exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipInflaterInputStream cannot be cast to
>   java.io.FileInputStream

Is there any way to do this?i intend to make zip extracting faster

Code for extracting ZipEntry

```
  FileChannel inChannel = fileinputStream.getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = fileoutputStream.getChannel();
        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(),
                    outChannel);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            if (inChannel != null) inChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null) outChannel.close();
        }
```